# Failed to start JFrog Open Source artifactory on Mac OS

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am trying to set-up JFrog OSS on mac-os. I followed all the instructions listed on the below installation page:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-Mac(Darwin)Installation

But on starting Artifactory using the command `$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryctl` as mentioned in Step 5 of above link, the below error is appearing. Any clue of the fix?

```
$ $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryctl
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/installerCommon.sh: line 2850: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/installerCommon.sh: line 2850: `    JF_PRODUCT_HOME=${homeDir} ${VALIDATE_BINARY} run ${DIAGNOSTICSYAMLFILEPATH} &>>$SYSTEM_DIAGNOSTICS_LOG_FILE'
[ERROR] Unable to source /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/installerCommon.sh, please check if the adnansohail user has permissions to perform this action
```

Comment: What shell is the script using?  &>> might be bash specific, you may be able to change the script to do `JF_PRODUCT_HOME=${homeDir} ${VALIDATE_BINARY} run ${DIAGNOSTICSYAMLFILEPATH} >> $SYSTEM_DIAGNOSTICS_LOG_FILE 2&>1' as a work-around.  Not sure if the 2nd error is related, or if you also don't have permission to write to$SYSTEM_DIAGNOSTICS_LOG_FILE.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for raising this. This is found and fixed in Artifactory 7.12. Please upgrade the version and try out.

Comment: I think version 7.12 is yet not uploaded on jfrog site. I just downloaded the latest version, and it gave me version 7.11.5.

Comment: Hey @AdnanSohail It should be released anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks... it worked with latest 7.12.5 release